# Count number of div tags inside a form

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to to count the number of div tags inside a specific form using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this

```
var totalDivCount= $('#formid div').length;

var totalDivCountThroughFind= $('form').find('div').length;
```

Comment: in your hurry to answer quickly, you forgot to close single quote :D

Answer (score 4):

Of course it is.

```
// using context
var myform = $('form');

var divs = $('div', myform).length;

// getting directly
var divs = $('form div').length;

// through find
var divs = $('form').find('div').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.size()` method

```
$("#formID div").size()
```

Comment: Note that this method is deprecated since jQuery 1.8.